# Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key in header of AJAX Bing web search API requests

Tags: azure, bing-api

We're working to switch from Google CSE to Bing's Web Search API.
The `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` is visible in a request header (called with an AJAX request).

How do we protect it from use by a third party?

(Note: We don't have any experience with Azure tools.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be embedding the subscription key into a client-side query.  Your search queries should go from the client-> your server -> Bing server and then back the same way.

This information, although [on the Image Search page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-image-search/search-the-web), applies to all Bing Searches:

> *All requests must be made from a server. You may not make calls from a client.*
>
> Although there are some cases where client-side calls are acceptable, such as internal-use cases, client-side is strongly not recommended.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply.
To avoid soliciting the server we would not want to make him play the role of proxy.

We will do as advocated.

Thank you.